# What effect has the favorite and shunned government?

Tags: civilization-3

[All of the civilizations](http://www.civfanatics.com/civ3/civilizations) list a "Favorite Government" and a "Shunned Government".  What effect does this have on gameplay?

In other words, how would being a [French](http://www.civfanatics.com/civ3/french.php) Monarchy compare to being a [Viking](http://www.civfanatics.com/civ3/vikings.php) Monarchy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has an effect during Diplomacy with the AI. The AI will be more friendly and less likely to attack you if you are using its favorite government, and will be less friendly and more likely to be hostile if you use the Shunned government.  I don't remember if Civ 3 had this, but in some Civs the AI would also sometimes request that you change to its favorite government.

It doesn't have any effect on what the government bonuses are or anything like that.  It is purely a diplomacy thing.

Comment: Let me get this straight, the AI would be happier if I'm using *the AI's* favorite government?

Comment: Correct.  They approve of your choice, and are thus more willing to deal with you.  So the favorite government of your own civ is completely irrelevant.